# java string replaceall first character after certain string to lower case

Tags: java, str-replace

I have a requirement to replace all the character within a string to lower case if it is followed by some string like "is".

For example:

```
String a = "name=xyz,isSalaried=Y,address=abc,isManager=N,salary=1000";
```

it should get converted to

```
"name=xyz,salaried=Y,address=abc,manager=N,salary=1000"
```

I am not very good at regular expression but I think can use it to achieve the required output.
It will be great if someone can help me out.

Comment: Java 9: `Pattern.compile("is([A-Z])").matcher(a).replaceAll(m -> m.group(1).toLowerCase())`

Comment: @shmosel that's a nice one - you should post it as an answer!

Comment: @Shmosel - It's looks a precise and very right solution, but the problem is we are working on JDK 7

Answer (score 0):

Your solution requires basic understanding of String and String methods in java.
Here is one working example. Although, it might not be the most efficient one.
NOTE:- **YOU ASKED FOR A REGEX SOLUTION.BUT THIS IS USING PURE STRING METHODS**

```
public class CheckString{
    public static void main(String[] ar){
        String s = "name=xyz,isSalaried=Y,address=abc,isManager=N,salary=1000";
        String[] arr = s.split(",");
        String ans = "";
        int i = 0;
        for(String text : arr){
            int index = text.indexOf("=");
            String before = text.substring(0,index).replace("is","").toLowerCase();
            String after = text.substring(index);
            if(i!=(arr.length-1)){
                ans += before + after + ",";
                i++;
            }
            else{
                ans += before + after;  
            }
        }
        System.out.println(ans);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
first match the string and replace in a loop

```
    String a = "name=xyz,isSalaried=Y,address=abc,isManager=N,salary=1000";

    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("is(.*?)=").matcher(a);//.matcher(a).replaceAll(m -> m.group(1).toLowerCase());

    while (matcher.find()) {
        String matchedString = matcher.group(1);

        a = a.replace("is"+matchedString,matchedString.toLowerCase());
    }
    System.out.printf(a);
```